# What to do when ESLint rule "prefer-destructuring" makes no sense

Tags: javascript, eslint

In many cases the rule `"prefer-destructuring"` of ESLint is pretty weird. Consider the following example:

```js
obj.someVar = myList[0];
```

The linter is warning me in both cases.

What's the expected behavior that the linter wants? I can use a temp var to save the value of the list item and later on do the rest of the logic, but I don't see any benefit in it. Any ideas what's the reason for that?

**EDIT:**

I can see the benefit of the rule in some situations, i.e:

```js
// bad
const someVar = myList[0];

// good
const [ someVar ] = myList;
```

But when the assignment is not directly to a var (like when assigning a property of an object) the rule seems irrelevant.

Comment: The first example would be solved by `const [firstItem] = myList; obj.someVar = firstItem;`

Comment: I know. That's what I said - I can easily split each of the examples to multiple lines, but there's no benefit in it in my opinion. sometimes destructuring makes sense and sometimes it isn't, but why to force me to use it for the latter case?

Comment: if you find it useful in general but not for specific examples you can use `// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-destructuring` before those

Comment: Every single linting rule is a suggestion, not an immutable law. You can always tweak the rules or disable them temporarily or permanently.

Comment: or if you don´t like this rule at all you can add `"rules": {
    "prefer-destructuring": ["warning", {"object": false, "array": false}]
  }` to your eslintrc in order to override it

Comment: I know that the rules can be disabled, either globally or in a specific case, but I'm trying to find the logic behind the people that defined them. Almost any other rule that I've seen makes a lot of sense, but this one doesn't and I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What ESLint expects for `obj.someVar = myList[0]` is:

```js
let obj = {};
let myList = [1,2];

[obj.someVar] = myList;

console.dir(obj);
```

Here is a link to an Issue about that topic [prefer-destructuring flags a property assignment #11584](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11584)